# Testing if file exists but get nullpointexception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public class ReadConfig  {

    private File configFile; 

    public boolean testConfig(){
        if(Utils.isWindows()){
            File configFile = new File("C:/config.properties");
        }
        else{
            File configFile = new File("/config.properties");
        }
        if(configFile.exists() && !configFile.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println(configFile + "found!");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            try {
                configFile.createNewFile();
                System.out.println(configFile + "created!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives back a null point exception at the following line

```
if(configFile.exists() && !configFile.isDirectory()){
```

It seems to me that it should return false, why would it throw a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Which language? And where do you initially define the variable `configFile`?

Comment: Language is java, i updated the op

Comment: Is there also a field called `configFile` in the class?

Comment: Yes, i just added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the statements in your `if` and `else` branch initialize a new variable called `configFile`, instead of using the field. Removing `File` should do the trick, e.g.:

```
if(Utils.isWindows()){
    configFile = new File("C:/config.properties");
} else {
   configFile = new File("/config.properties");
}
```